# No network connection available

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 but it does not detect my network. Do I have to do this manually? Or is there an automatic network discovery tool?

I am running strictly wireless right now and I did add wireless network details but it does not connect.
The output of `lspci -nn | grep Network` is:

```
Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corp Wireless 7265[8086:095a] rev 61
```

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you connect via wireless? Which are you trying to fix, wired or wireless?

Answer (score 0):

You should automatically detect a wired connection to your computer.

Wireless would require you to connect to it.  Look for the network indicator in your panel, select the network you are trying to connect to, and fill in any useful details like the WiFi password.  From then on, it should auto-connect to the given access point.

Personally I'm using XUbuntu 13.10, so something as basic as this should be the same (or at least very close to what you need for an answer).

If this answer helps you, feel free to hit the checkmark next to the answer so I get credit for helping you.  If someone else gives a better answer, then please give them credit instead. :)

Comment: I am running strictly wireless right now and I did add wireless network details but it does not connect. Not sure why.

Comment: In that case, please open a terminal session and type in the command 'iwconfig'.  Is there a section entitled 'wlan0', and if so, does it have an ESSID?

Comment: It says "ESSID: off/any

Comment: Are you able to connect to any other WiFi access points using this computer?  (Trying to rule out anything wrong with the laptop as opposed to possible issues with the wifi access point you are trying to link to.)  Also, do you have any other devices that can successfully access and use the AP you are trying to connect to?

Comment: With Linux wireless networking is not available. Everything works when I use Windows. Maybe I am missing a driver that I am not aware of for wireless networking to be enabled on Linux.

Comment: Then I would recommend loading the WiFi diagnostics above in the comments to your question as written by David Foerster and edit your question accordingly so we can find out WHY you are not getting any wireless connectivity to any AP.